# How can I add a unique "row number" key to a MS Access table that has no unique keys?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a table `T1` in Microsoft Access, with columns `Name` and `EmployeeName`. It doesn't have any unique key. How can I add a unique row number `ID` to each row?

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE [T1] ADD COLUMN [ID] COUNTER PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
 Alter Table Table_Name
 Add P_Key Number AUTOINCREMENT;
```

Answer (score -1):

When you create a table in Access it will automatically assign a unique ID to each record, that is every row of information.

Comment: He didn't say he created a table? He could be importing a table, in which case you need to manually assign a primary key.

Comment: When I have imported tables into Access is has automatically assigned a unique ID.

Comment: When you link a table it does not.